# Problem while invoking a Function from a Class

Tags: c#

I have a class that name **Cleint** in that i have a function ,i want to make a three instantiate from Cleint with diffrent result of a Function but the results are same here is my code:

Programm.cs:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cleint B = new Cleint();
            Cleint k = new Cleint();
            Cleint S = new Cleint();
            Console.WriteLine(B.GenerateAddress());
            Console.WriteLine(k.GenerateAddress());
            Console.WriteLine(S.GenerateAddress());
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
```

and Cleint.cs:

```
class Cleint
    {
        public string GenerateAddress()
        {
            var parts = new List<string>();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int newPart = random.Next(0, 255);
                parts.Add(newPart.ToString());
            }
            string address = string.Join(".", parts);
            p;
            return address;
        }
    }
```

thank's for your help

Comment: Try seeding your Random - http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number generator not working the way I had planned (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

Comment: I believe you might mean `Client`, just as an fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Random` is not really random - it is pseudo random and the default constructor uses the current time as the seed for the sequence.

When called in quick succession, this time will be the same and the sequence be the same.

You can use a static field to ensure you are using the same `Random` instance if you are only ever going to have one thread (as `Random` is not thread safe):

```
class Cleint
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public string GenerateAddress()
    {
        var parts = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int newPart = random.Next(0, 255);
            parts.Add(newPart.ToString());
        }
        string address = string.Join(".", parts);

        return address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you're using random number generation - you're creating a new instance of `Random` in each case.

See [my article on random numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for details, but basically you should use the same instance of `Random` for all the calls.

Assuming your classes aren't designed to be multithreaded, you could change it to *either* have a `Random` field in `Client`, or have a `Random` parameter in `GenerateAddress`. Either way, you'd create a single instance in `Main` and pass a reference to that same instance for all three cases.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Always instantiate as few `Random` classes as possible (always make them class-level variables).

Comment: @SpikeX: Well, while bearing in mind that they're not thread-safe... you don't want a static field.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Random object, it uses the current time on your PC as the seed for it's generator. If you create many Random objects in a fast succession, they'll generate the same "random" numbers.

Try creating a single Random object and generating from that.